# Read in text delimited file C

Tags: c, io

Still in the fiddling stage with C. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here but I think it has to do with pointers. Anyway. I'm trying to read in and parse a tab-delimited text file into a 2D array. The actual array is 6109 x 14, I allotted a bigger pointer array.

```
FILE *in = fopen("afile","rt");
// read the first line from the file
char line[2000];
int x=0;
int y=0;
char *result[7000][14];
char *curResult;
char delim[]= "\t";

while (fgets(line, 2000, in) != NULL) {
    printf("LINE IS %s\n",line);
    curResult=NULL;
    curResult = strtok(line,delim);
    y=0;
    while( curResult != NULL ) {
        result[x][y]= curResult;
        curResult = strtok( NULL, delim );
        y++;
    }
    x++;
}

//print a random line to check 
for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    printf("%s\n", result[50][i]);
```

The line I printed at the bottom which should be the 50th line prints the last line of the text file. I tried this with different numbers instead of 50 but they all print the same thing.

**EDIT: afile looks like this:**

```
  instance_id   batch_id    cmap_name   INN1    concentration (M)   duration (h)    cell2   array3  perturbation_scan_id    vehicle_scan_id4    scanner vehicle vendor  catalog_number  catalog_name
1   1   metformin   INN 0.00001 6   MCF7    HG-U133A    EC2003090503AA  EC2003090502AA  HP GeneArray Scanner    medium  Sigma-Aldrich   D5035   "1,1-dimethylbiguanide hydrochloride"
2   1   metformin   INN 0.00001 6   MCF7    HG-U133A    EC2003090504AA  EC2003090502AA  HP GeneArray Scanner    medium  Sigma-Aldrich   D5035   "1,1-dimethylbiguanide hydrochloride"
3   1   metformin   INN 0.0000001   6   MCF7    HG-U133A    EC2003090505AA  EC2003090502AA  HP GeneArray Scanner    medium  Sigma-Aldrich   D5035   "1,1-dimethylbiguanide hydrochloride"
4   1   metformin   INN 0.001   6   MCF7    HG-U133A    EC2003090506AA  EC2003090502AA  HP GeneArray Scanner    medium  Sigma-Aldrich   D5035   "1,1-dimethylbiguanide hydrochloride"
21  2   phenformin  INN 0.00001 6   MCF7    HG-U133A    EC2003091104AA  EC2003091102AA  HP GeneArray Scanner    medium  Sigma-Aldrich   P7045   phenformin hydrochloride
22  2   phenyl biguanide        0.00001 6   MCF7    HG-U133A    EC2003091105AA  EC2003091102AA  HP GeneArray Scanner    medium  Sigma-Aldrich   P19906  1-phenylbiguanide hydrochloride
23  2   valproic acid   INN 0.001   6   MCF7    HG-U133A    EC2003091106AA  EC2003091102AA  HP GeneArray Scanner    medium  Sigma-Aldrich   P4543   2-propylpentanoic acid
61  2a  metformin   INN 0.00001 6   MCF7    HG-U133A    EC2003091103AA  EC2003091102AA  HP GeneArray Scanner    medium  Sigma-Aldrich   D5035   "1,1-dimethylbiguanide hydrochloride"
```

Comment: Can you show the first few lines of "afile"??

Comment: I tried..im not sure how to format copied in text like that not all of those new lines are actually new lines ..I'll see if I can fix that though.

Comment: strtok return pointer of taken in line. Meaningless unless a copy of the token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine `line` is a big box where you can put a bunch of letters.
That's what you do with `fgets()`.

Next you point to specific letters inside that box.

Next you replace the contents of the box (another `fgets()` to the same variable `line`) and the pointers, of course still point to the same box, but now to the new letters.

You need to copy the characters (with `strcpy()`, **check that you have enough space first**) somewhere inside your loop.

Comment: Or to put it more explicitly, `strtok()` doesn't allocate any new space for anything.  It just hands out pointers to parts of its internal state.  So what it returns is unsafe to use as is.  You need to copy what it returns into memory you control.

Comment: Instead of my line that says result[x][y] = curResult I tried replacing it with strcpy(result[x][y],curResult); but I got a bad_access error.

Comment: Where did `result[x][y]` point to? You need to make sure you are copying to somewhere valid. I think you meant to have `char result[7000][14];` and `strcpy(result[x], curResult);`. Just make sure `curResult` has 13 or less characters.

Comment: Ohhhhh now I see. I think. Except I want to have a two dimensional matrix of strings? Like I want result[5][10] to say "josh" or whatever not each cell to hold a character. Can I do that?

Comment: Yes, of course. And to do that, your definition of `result` works ... **but** ... you need to allocate memory for the pointers. `result[x][y] = malloc(strlen(curResult) + 1); strcpy(result[x][y], curResult);` Remember to `free(result[x][y]);` when you no longer need the memory.